# ngOnchanges not triggering

Tags: typescript, angular7

I am calling companyInfo (component) which i am calling in Company report component (report componet) and i also displaying all the company names in the report page only (right side for quick access). Only once ngOnchanges working for the companyInfo component for the initial load of report, if i click other company from quick access ngOnchanges not triggering in companyInfo Component. How can i detect for every click?

```
<div id="CompanyInfo" class="ContentControl">
    <app-company-info [isInEdit]="isInEdit"></app-company-info>
</div>
```

CompanyInfo Component Ts file

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input,SimpleChanges  } from '@angular/core';
  export class CompanyInfoComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input()
  isInEdit: boolean;

  constructor(private _reportDataService: ReportDataService) { }
  ngOnInit() {

  }
  ngOnChanges( changes: SimpleChanges ){
      console.log( "CompanyInfoComponent" );
  }
}
```

Comment: Does `isInEdit` change with your click or whatever you do? If not then ngOnChanges will not trigger.

Comment: export class CompanyInfoComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges

Answer (score 0):

The Angular lifecycle hook method `ngOnChanges` is called before `ngOnInit` and whenever one or more data-bound input properties change. To make this work, your class must implement the interface `OnChanges`. In your case, to have the method invoked more than once, `isInEdit` must have its value changed after component initialisation.

In your `CompanyInfoComponent`, you want to display information of a company selected elsewhere. It makes sense to have another `@Input` property for let's say the ID of the selected company. Each time when this ID changes, you would have to request detailed information for the corresponding company.

```
@Input() companyID: number;

ngOnChanges( changes: SimpleChanges ){
  if (changes['companyID']) {
    // request company information 
  }
}
```

In the template, the company ID would be passed to the component follows:

```
<app-company-info [isInEdit]="isInEdit" [companyID]="selectedCompanyID"></app-company-info>
```